# PL/SQL Case WHEN with two constants followed by THEN expression

Tags: oracle, plsql

is it possible for somehow having a CASE with an OR option like below in PL/SQL ?

```
CASE selector 
   WHEN 'value1' OR 'value2' THEN S1; 
   WHEN 'value3' OR 'value4' THEN S2; 
   WHEN 'value3' THEN S3; 
   ... 
   ELSE Sn;  -- default case 
END CASE;
```

Comment: It is well documented: [Simple `CASE` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-3937FEB2-96A1-456B-AD9E-09B627DF0939), [Searched `CASE` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-control-statements.html#GUID-C7CBBE66-5E51-444E-BE92-C23ED662FE4D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather use `IN`:

```
SQL> declare
  2    selector varchar2(20);
  3    result   varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    selector := '10';
  6
  7    result := case when selector in ('10', '20') then 's1'
  8                   when selector in ('30', '40') then 's2'
  9                   else 'sn'
 10              end;
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || result);
 12  end;
 13  /
Result = s1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

You *can* use `OR`, though:

```
SQL> declare
  2    selector varchar2(20);
  3    result   varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    selector := '10';
  6
  7    result := case when selector = '10' or selector = '20' then 's1'
  8                   when selector = '30' or selector = '40' then 's2'
  9                   else 'sn'
 10              end;
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || result);
 12  end;
 13  /
Result = s1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Database 23c has added "dangling predicates" to case expressions in PL/SQL.

This enables you to list the selector at the start (like a simple case expression) with the righthand side of the comparison in the when clause. I.e. the condition and compared value.

e.g.:

```
declare
  selector varchar2(20);
  result   varchar2(20);
begin
  selector := 'value3';

  result := case selector
              when in ( 'value1', 'value2' ) then 's1' 
              when in ( 'value3', 'value4' ) then 's2'
              else 'sn'
            end;
  dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || result);
end;
/

Result = s2
```